# Magento API: get products from a category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, magento, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hi I can't find anywhere how to get a list of product by category id in Magento API. I am using Ruby XMLRPC library. When i call product.list, I get all my products, each one of them is like this:

```
{"product_id"=>"165", "sku"=>"mycomputer", 
"name"=>"My Computer", "set"=>"39", 
"type"=>"bundle", "category_ids"=>["27"]}, 
{"product_id"=>"166", "sku"=>"HTC Touch Diamond", "name"=>"HTC Touch Diamond", 
"set"=>"38", "type"=>"simple", "category_ids"=>["8"]}
```

`client.call('call',session_id,'product.list')` gives me every product.
I tried `client.call('call',session_id,'product.list',[:name=>{:like=>"%%computer"}])` gives me products with name containing computer. 
I tried

```
client.call('call',session_id,'product.list',[:category_ids=>{:include=>"8"}])
client.call('call',session_id,'product.list',[:category_ids=>"8"])
client.call('call',session_id,'product.list',[:category_ids=>["8"]])
```

all these fail. I even tried replacing "category_ids" with "category_id"

In addition, the following line is not working either. What did I do wrong?

```
client.call('call',session_id,'product.info',[:product_id=>xxx])
```

Neither Magento API and Ruby XMLRPC API can tell me what the correct syntax should be. Anyone has any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`catalog_category.assignedProducts`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/catalog_category#catalog_category.assignedproducts) API method.

From the documentation:

> Retrieve list of assigned products
>
> Return: array
>
> Arguments:
>
> int $categoryId - category ID mixed $store - store ID or code
>
> Aliases:
>
> category.assignedProducts

Comment: thanks. I think you are right. Do you also happen to know how to call product.info with id correctly?